# @ModelAttribute for Rest PUT - request param null

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, put

I need to populate my pojo class based on the request param 'type'.
so I have code like

```
@ModelAttribute
public void getModelObject(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap modelMap) {
    String typeCombo = request.getParameter("type");
    System.out.println("typeCombo: " + typeCombo);
    if (typeCombo != null) {
        if (condition) {
            modelMap.addAttribute("modelObj", new ClassB()); //ClassB extends ClassA
        } else if (another condition) {
            modelMap.addAttribute("modelObj", new ClassC()); //ClassC extends ClassA
        } else {
            System.out.println("no type found");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("typecombo null");
    }

}
```

I use above method to get create correct subclasses which will be used to add / update. The above one works fine in case of "POST" - for creating a record. But for "PUT" request.getParameter("type") always returns null. So for editing, I'm not able to get correct subclasses.

Below are my post and put request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*")
@ResponseBody
public String addCredentials(@ModelAttribute("modelObj") Credential credential,
                             ModelMap modelMap) {
//code
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=*/*")
@ResponseBody
public Credential editCredential(@ModelAttribute ("modelObj") Credential credential, @PathVariable long id, ModelMap model) {
```

//code
}

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to configure the [HttpPutFormContentFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HttpPutFormContentFilter.html). If you want to be able to retrieve the attributes (PUT is different as POST in regards to parameter handling).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, any pointers to look for sample?

Answer (score 0):

Register the filter [HttpPutFormContentFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HttpPutFormContentFilter.html) like this:

```
<beans:bean id="httpPutFormContentFilter"
class="org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter" />
```